# How do I integrate an InDesign PDF into my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, download, adobe-indesign, pdfkit

I have been given a task to create a rails app where you can purchase a PDF and then download it. I know that the PDF will have been made in InDesign, but I have no idea how I can integrate this into my app. I have had a look at PDF kit and that coverts HTML into a PDF, so is not really what I need.

Does anyone know whether this is possible and have any ideas, would be really grateful.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You can export a file using InDesign javascript or applescript. For example, to export the currently open document to the desktop on a mac:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

var outputFile = File("~/Desktop/temp.pdf");

doc.asynchronousExportFile(ExportFormat.pdfType, outputFile);
```

If you're looking for something a little more involved, take a look at [IDMLlib](http://idmllib.com/ILWebsite/index) or [InDesign Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/indesignserver.html). They might contain the functionality you need, although I don't have any experience with them.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will upvote you once my reputation improves so I am able to!